# Changes to a java application server not showing after deployment

Tags: java, shell, jar, server, cloud

I'm using a system which runs various Java programs from a cloud server. The programs use external command line tools. Our programs build up commands and send them to another java program, an application server, to further process and execute the command.

I'm working on something which involves editing the application server. I make changes, package it as a jar, deploy it to the server, and then run a script which executes the application server. The script uses the location of the jar file on the server as the path of the executable. However, none of my changes appear after running and deploying.

To make matters more confusing, even DELETING the jar on the server and stopping the process does not make any changes, i.e. running a request from one of the programs is still successful. Deleting this jar ought to break things, right?

I'm sure the jar path that the script is pointing to is correct. I guess my question is, is there anything further that needs to be done to edit an application server program running on a server?

Comment: You've restarted the server, right?

Comment: Is your app deployed as one instance only or in a cluster with multiple instances running on different servers?

Comment: @JoeC Yes I have

Comment: @tsolakp I believe only 1 instance? There is only one server from which everything runs.

Comment: I suggest you reach out to the customer support department of your cloud provider.  All we can do is speculate, which is neither helpful to you nor future visitors.